# Why am I getting a negative sum? $\frac{1}{1\cdot2} - \frac{1}{2\cdot3}+\frac{1}{3\cdot4}-\frac{1}{4\cdot5}+ \cdots$

Tags: sequences-and-series, summation

The infinite sum I want to find.

> $$\frac{1}{1\cdot2} - \frac{1}{2\cdot3}+\frac{1}{3\cdot4}-\frac{1}{4\cdot5}+ \cdots$$

My attempt at it

$$\begin{align} &\;\sum_{n=1}^{\infty} \frac{1}{(2n-1)(2n)} - \sum_{n=1}^{\infty} \frac{1}{(2n)(2n+1)} \\[4pt]
=&\;\sum_{n=1}^{\infty} \left(\frac{1}{2n-1} - \frac{1}{2n}\right) - \sum_{n=1}^{\infty} \left(\frac{1}{2n} - \frac{1}{2n+1}\right) \\[4pt]
=&\;\sum_{n=1}^{\infty} \left(\frac{1}{2n-1} + \frac{1}{2n+1}\right) - 2 \sum_{n=1}^{\infty} \frac{1}{2n} \\[4pt]
=&\;\left(\frac{1}{1}+\frac{1}{3}+\frac{1}{5}+\cdots\right) + 
\left(\frac{1}{3}+\frac{1}{5}+\frac{1}{7}+\cdots\right) 
- 2\left(\frac{1}{2}+\frac{1}{4}+\frac{1}{6}+\cdots\right) \\[4pt]
=&\;1 + 2\left(\frac{1}{3}+\frac{1}{5}+\frac{1}{7}+\cdots\right) - 
\left(\frac{1}{1}+\frac{1}{2}+\frac{1}{3}+\cdots\right) \\[4pt]
=\;&-1+1-\frac{1}{2}+\frac{1}{3}-\frac{1}{4}+\cdots \\[4pt]
=\;&\ln 2 - 1 
\end{align}$$

The answer I got here is negative, while the series seems to be positive. What is the mistake here?

Comment: Your original sequence converges absolutely, meaning you can reorder terms as you wish. However, in your intermediate steps you manipulate the terms themselves and end up using and manipulating the harmonic series, and that you cannot do. Specifically, your error is thinking that $$\sum\left(\frac1{2i-1}-\frac1{2i+1}\right)=\sum\frac1{2i-1}-\sum\frac1{2i+1}$$

Comment: @Arthur, I thought the original series converges only conditionally? Are you sure it converges absolutely? The denominators seem to be in arithmetic progression, I don't think it has absolute convergence

Comment: Yes, the original series converges absolutely. Compare it to $\frac1{1^2} + \frac1{2^2} + \cdots = \frac{\pi^2}6$.

Comment: @Arthur, thank you, I thought the `.` symbol meant the fractional part, not mutliplication. The importance of proper formatting

Comment: @YuriyS What proper formatting? In many parts of the world (I believe England is included here, from what I've seen written on Numberphile), elementary school students learn `.` as a multiplication symbol. So it's more about how you ought to be aware of it as a person who frequents an international math forum than the other way around.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, the sum is positive. Note that instead of 
$$= \sum_{n=1}^{\infty} \left(\frac{1}{2n-1} + \frac{1}{2n+1}\right) - 2 \sum_{n=1}^{\infty} \frac{1}{2n}$$
which is indefinite since the series are divergent, you should have the limit as $N$ goes to $\infty$ of
$$\sum_{n=1}^{N} \left(\frac{1}{2n-1} + \frac{1}{2n+1}\right) - 2 \sum_{n=1}^{N} \frac{1}{2n}\\
=-1+2\left(\frac{1}{1}+\frac{1}{3}+\frac{1}{5}+\dots+\frac{1}{2N-1}\right)  +\frac{1}{2N+1} - 2\left(\frac{1}{2}+\frac{1}{4}+\frac{1}{6}+\dots+\frac{1}{2N}\right)$$
which is a different thing. What is its limit as $N$ goes to $\infty$?

More simply, you may consider the partial sum and then take the limit as $N$ goes to $\infty$
$$S_N=\sum_{n=1}^{N}\frac{(-1)^{n+1}}{n(n+1)}=\sum_{n=1}^{N}\frac{(-1)^{n+1}}{n}+\sum_{n=1}^{N}\frac{(-1)^{n+2}}{n+1}=
\sum_{n=1}^{N}\frac{(-1)^{n+1}}{n}+\sum_{n=2}^{N+1}\frac{(-1)^{n+1}}{n}\\
=-1+2\sum_{n=1}^{N}\frac{(-1)^{n+1}}{n}+\frac{(-1)^{N+2}}{N+1}\to -1+2\ln(2)>0.$$

Comment: Oh. So basically my mistake was I just neglected the last terms and the number of terms indirectly by just leaving it to the dots......

Comment: Yes, you neglected an infinite number of (infinitesimal) terms.

Comment: Oh. Thanks for helping.